# Problems saving a text file with a folder

Tags: java, windows, macos, save, text-files

Just wondering if you could point me in the right direction. My code below is where I stand at the moment, problem I have is that it will save `data.txt` to location, but only when I dont add a folder eg.  `"/data.txt"` works, but `"/folder/data.txt"` doesnt work. Logic tells me that my code doesnt create a folder, but instead tells the computer to save data.txt into a folder called folder. My first question, how is my code modified to achieve this?

Second and most important, I have been looking over the net and Stack Overflow and have been given plenty of examples from `user.home`, `user.dir` and more, they all work, but again without the folder in the way as described in part 1. My main goal is to hide (not literally) a save file in a  folder, eg. `C:/Program Files/SysAuth/data.txt`. This is a simple attempt to not allow users to modify scores, primitive security is all that is required. My main problem is that I would like the filepath to be compatible with both windows and mac. I can't test anything for compatibility as I do not have access to a Mac. Hope you can help.

```
public statiic void save(){
    String str = "Congratulations";

    file = System.getPropery("user.home");
    fileName = (file + "/folder/data.txt");

    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(str);
        bw.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: nvm i didn't read it good you need to make the folder a file and just do file.mkdirs

Comment: The first question could be solved with New File(~/folder/data.txt) and then call mkdirs on the file object. After that you can place the file object in your outputstream. You can also set permissions like readability with the file object or create a hidden folder.

Comment: @user, I have used your methods previously, but again I wasnt sure if this was compatible with mac, but Il do it here aswell then. I also read that literally hidding a file flares up security warning in some OS's. Is this the case?  At Emrage, thanks Il have a look into this "." as you mentioned.

Comment: @dazbrad the "." will only create a file in the current directory.  A dot before a folder Name will make the folder hidden (on Unix like systems)

Comment: Ahh, right ok. Ima go and play around with my code and get back to you guys. Cheers for the pointers fellas.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're asking is how to create the parent directories.

```
File file = new File(filename);
file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

See documentation for mkdirs method [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs())

The final code would look like this:

```
public static void save(){
    String str = "Congratulations";

    file = System.getPropery("user.home");
    File textFile = new File(file + "/folder/data.txt");

    try {
        textFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(textFile);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(str);
        bw.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As for the second part of the question...please don't go hiding things in my "Program Files". One of  the proper (and easiest) ways of doing this is with the [Java Preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html). There's a nice tutorial [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPreferences/article.html) which actually does not require any file manipulation at all.

You could also encrypt the file using a library like [Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/) but that's probably overkill in this case.

Comment: This is close to what im trying to say. Using this example, I would like to save it somwhere that isnt so commonly visited by the user, somewher more scary for newbs  to start playing around and editing Using windows, I would probs opt to place my file in C:/Program Files/.....create an authorative sounding folder here/data.txt. But of course, mac doesnt use C:/, or program file. Do you see where Im coming from?

Comment: Added some info that should help solve the second issue. I didn't add any code as the change would require removing the solution of the first question. In this case, the two questions are only loosely related and it's difficult to provide a proper solution to both with one answer.